# In Django, How to get the currently running app from within a model on another app?

Tags: django, model, url-routing, url-pattern

Basically i am trying to use *.get_absolute_url()* to return dynamic links in relative to the current app running, in other words reverse the model url to a different url based on which app being called.

Let me try to explain what i am trying to do by example, We have three apps

- Blog (serves as a shared data layer, contains models for post, authors ... etc)
- BloggerWay (serves as a view layer number one, uses the Blog app models to display content in some given layout)
- TumblrWay (serves as another view layer, again uses the Blog app models to display content in some given layout)

My urls.py files goes like

```
----------
*Project.urls.py*
----------
urlpatterns= [
  url('/blogger/', include(BloggerWay.urls.py, namespace='blogger'),
  url('/tumblr/', include(TumblrWay.urls.py, namespace='tumblr'),]
----------
*BloggerWay.urls.py*
----------
urlpatterns= [
  url('/post/(?P<id>\d+)', Blog.as_view(), name='blog'),]
----------
 *TumblrWay.urls.py*
----------
urlpatterns= [
  url('/post/(?P<id>\d+)', Blog.as_view(), name='blog'),]
```

---

**My question is** How can i define *.get_absolute_url()* method for the Post model so it knows which app we are in and return the correct url to it.

example:
if in BloggerWay return '/blogger/post'
if in TumblrWay return '/tumblr/post'

---

I know that i can use the *reverse()* function to get the url for a given named pattern and that it accepts a *current_app=* argument but my problem is how can i get the running app so i can pass it.

```
class Post(...):
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    WhoAmI = ... #get current app here, BUT HOW!
    return reverse('post', current_app=WhoAmI)
```

---

**Solutions that i want to avoid:**

- I can inherit the Post class in both of the apps, override the *.get_absolute_url()* there, hardcoding the name space of each app in it. Then use the class in my app instead of directly using the one defined as model/table.(while offcourse avoid performing migrations for that class, even better define it somewhere else than models.py)

Answer (score 0):

Implement another property for get_url() for your class.
The reverse function should includes "namespace:name"
e.g

```
class Post(...):...
    def get_blogger_url(self):
        return reverse("blogger:post", kwargs={"id":self.id}) # for Blogger
    def get_tumblr_url(self):
        return reverse("tumblr:post", kwargs={"id":self.id}) # for Tumblr
```

Comment: Thank you @Barack for the suggestion. It will work but i guess it won't be efficient for two reasons. _First_ when dealing with a large number of apps that utilize the same model's app, we will end up having a method for each of them. Also the developer will need to remember those methods name when using them in his template as opposed to just using the get_absolute_url() method. _Second_ hard coding the name space means that the model's app would be dependent on the name spaces the developer uses.

Comment: To continue: The developer will end up modifying the model's app, which in turn means that the app will lose its pluggable ability.